# splitting a list based on the values of a second list

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to set up a loop that will run through a list of power readings and sort it into two seperate lists based on the minimum temperature recorded that night (checking for aircon use). But i can't seem to get the list to sort.

```
Pwr_Usd = [0, 9, 13, 11, 13, 8.5, 12.5, 14, 10, 8.5, 7.5, 21, 7, 8, 12, 17, 6, 12, 11.25, 12.75, 8]
Temp_Min = [13.8, 14.1, 13.7, 16.9]
Ovr_Usd = PwrUsd[1::4]  # Overnight Usage netween 12am and 6am

## Air Conditioning
AirCon = []

## Standby Power
StbyPwr = []


for i in Ovr_Usd:
    if i > 16 in Temp_Min:
        AirCon.append(i)

else:
    StbyPwr.append(i)

print(AirCon)
print(StbyPwr)
```

In a perfect world I would end up with two lists

```
Aircon = [12]
stbyPwr = [9, 8.5, 8.5, 8]
```

but i am open to any suggestion that would let me run a temperature list against a powerlist and get sort the nights where its too cold for aircon power usage to be a factor. its worth noting that all the lists are organised sequentially over time. with Temp_min being over a week, and every Pwr_Usd reading being 6 hours apart, hence why Ovr_Usd only selects every 4th value for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

for sorting lists in python, try python's .sort list method:

```
pwr_usd = [0, 9, 13, 11, 13, 8.5, 12.5, 14, 10, 8.5, 7.5, 21, 7, 8, 12, 17, 6, 12, 11.25, 12.75, 8]
temp_min = [13.8, 14.1, 13.7, 16.9]

pwr_usd.sort()
temp_min.sort()

print(pwr_usd)
print(temp_min)
```

and the output will be:

```
[0, 6, 7, 7.5, 8, 8, 8.5, 8.5, 9, 10, 11, 11.25, 12, 12, 12.5, 12.75, 13, 13, 14, 17, 21]
[13.7, 13.8, 14.1, 16.9]
```

and then do your desired seperation and classification using a list comprehension or good old for loops. in the case of a list comprehension:

```
air_con = [i for i in pwr_usd if i > 16 and i in temp_min]
```

though this returns an empty list when i run it, and that is because none of the values in `pwr_usd` are actually in `temp_min` (they have to be EXACTLY the same)

SIDENOTE: it is a good practice to maintain the conventions in naming variables. for example instead of `PwrUsd`, go with `pwr_usd`

Comment: sorry I guess i need to clarify a bit. temp_min is organised by date (sequential days), hence why Ovr_Usd (overnight power usage) only selects every 4th value of Pwr_Usd(6 hour measurements over the same time period). So what i want is to seperate Ovr_Usd into two lists based on whether the corresponding temperature is over 16C.

Comment: so a couple of things i think is wrong with the code: first, what is `FdStrge` and what is the usage for it? the definition of `FdStrge` is not included in the code. i am sorry for my inconvenience but i think the question is not very clear or does not correspond with the code provided.

Comment: also, my i suggest using a dictionary or a 2D list if the values in any list, have a corresponding date to them.

Comment: sorry, FdStrge (food storage) is a leftover from a later piece of code, i'll remove it. Basically it was me calculating what amount of power the fridges were drawing and separating it from the Base load of the house

Comment: right. well my suggestion is that you try a dictionary for matching corresponding times / dates with any other element that you want. you can do it with lists, but its gonna be a little confusing.